# IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method (Math.max.apply)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm not a huge JS writer - so this maybe really easy - but I'm getting the above error in the following line of code:

```
max_height = Math.max.apply(Math, this.headlines.map(function(e) {
        return jQuery(e).height(); }));
```

Its not my code - but any pointers on how to fix this would be appreciated! Thanks

PS. works perfectly on Chrome/Safari...

Comment: Is that the exact error you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first (only) observation, is that you're using `.map()` which is defined in Javascript 1.6 and IE8 only supports Javascript 1.5 (as far as I'm aware)

Perhaps try using a polyfill or a library of pollyfils like modernizr etc.
See: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Or.

Write your code such that it doesnt rely on features unsupported by IE8.

Or.

Seeing as you're using jQuery. you could use jquery to provide the `.map()` functionality, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

```
max_height = Math.max.apply(Math, jQuery.map(this.headlines, function(e) {
    return jQuery(e).height(); }));
```

Comment: did you try the shim/polyfil, or not depending on 1.6 ie: no native `.map()` in IE8

Comment: Sorry Christopher - was being really dim - obviously late night! The Jquery.map worked fine, there was an error elsewhere.. I hate IE!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: or use a library like underscorejs- it has a map function which works in IE8 and has other list operations which are really useful.