# Why isn't this JS working in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, css

I found this snippet that gives me the max height of an object, it works great in everything except for in ie8. Is there something I can change that will make it work properly?

```
    function thisHeight(){
        return $(this).height();
    }

    $("#new-deals ul.centerSpace").height(function() {
        var dealNameHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, $(this).find(".deal-name").map(thisHeight));      
        $(".deal-name").css({height: dealNameHeight});
    });
```

Comment: What does not work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471437/ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-math-max-apply#8472849) : if it answers you, delete this question and don't accept this answer has an answer. (all credits to [Blazermonger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901048/blazemonger) who flagued the duplication)

[IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method (Math.max.apply)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471437/ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-math-max-apply#8472849)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support `map()`; as a fallback you could use underscore that provides an implementation of `map()` it the browser doesn't support it and allows you to pass a context.

This lets me introduces the second problem: you may have an issue with the context that must be passed over `thisHeight`.

```
var arr = _.map($(this).find(".deal-name"), function(el) { 
   return thisHeight.call(el); //note that el and this are not identical
}, this);
Math.max.apply(Math, arr); //if you use underscore
```

If the context is not passed over `thisHeight`, `this` is likely to refer to the global object, which is `window`.